# Select Based on Column Value in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to get values of `TIMESTAMP` and `STRING_VALUE` based on selected `ID`.
Suppose My Selected `ID` is `4259,4226` and `4259` 
Then It should select `TIMESTAMP` and `STRING_VALUE` for selected `ID` using CASE Statement.
I have tried Below query but returning Into Error

```
CREATE TABLE "DRL_FTO3_DI1_A0"
(
  "VARIABLE" integer,
  "CALCULATION" integer,
  "TIMESTAMP_S" integer,
  "TIMESTAMP_MS" integer,
  "VALUE" double precision,
  "STATUS" integer,
  "GUID" character(36),
  "STRVALUE" character varying(50)
)

INSERT INTO "DRL_FTO3_DI1_A0"(
            "VARIABLE", "CALCULATION", "TIMESTAMP_S", "TIMESTAMP_MS", "VALUE", 
            "STATUS", "GUID", "STRVALUE")
    VALUES (4226, 0, 1451120925, 329,0 , 1078067200, '', 'BATCH 1'),
           (4306, 0, 1451120925, 329,0 , 1078067200, '', 'BATCH 2'),
           (4311, 0, 1451120925, 329,0 , 1078067200, '', '2')
```

Now Suppose Out of three Variable(4226,4306,4311) I want to select 4226 and 4311

```
SELECT ((TIMESTAMP WITHOUT Time Zone 'epoch' + "TIMESTAMP_S" * INTERVAL '1 second') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT Time Zone,
SUM(CASE WHEN "VARIABLE" = 4226 Then "STRVALUE" END) as 'A',
SUM(CASE WHEN "VARIABLE" = 4311 Then "STRVALUE" END) as 'B'
FROM "DRL_FTO3_DI1_A0"
GROUP BY "TIMESTAMP_S"
ORDER BY "TIMESTAMP_S";


 TIMESTAMP_S                         A            B
 2015-12-26 14:38:45                BATCH_1       2
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Perhaps example data (and error message)  would help?

Comment: There is my Output Too

Comment: Will the `crosstab()` function do what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i write the query for crosstab in my case

Comment: This is what i have tried using crosstab but resulting into error SELECT * FROM   crosstab(
      'SELECT "VARIABLE","TIMESTAMP_S","STRVALUE"
       FROM  "DRL_FTO3_DI1_A0"
       ORDER  BY 2')  
AS ct ("TIMESTAMP_S" Integer, "A" text, "B" text);

Comment: ERROR:  return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible
********** Error **********

ERROR: return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible
SQL state: 42601 This is the error i am getting

Answer (score 1):

This Is the Query using crosstab and It Works

```css
SELECT *
    FROM  crosstab (
        $$SELECT "VARIABLE", "TIMESTAMP_S", "STRVALUE"
         FROM   "DRL_FTO3_DI1_A0"
         WHERE  "VARIABLE" = ANY (array[4306,4226])
         ORDER  BY 1,2$$
    ) 
        AS
    t (            
        "TIMESTAMP_S" integer,                
        "A" character varying,
        "B" character varying
    );
```